# sorting list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
L = [{'status': 1, 'country': 'France'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'canada'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'usa'}]
```

How to sort this list by `country` (or by `status`) elements, ASC/DESC.

Comment: If these dictionaries are all matching (ie. they all have a 'status' key and a 'country' key, and no other keys), consider using instances of a class created by `collections.namedtuple` instead. It will make a lot of your code, including sorting, much simpler to read and write. See [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for details

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `list.sort()` to sort the list in-place or `sorted` to get a new list:

```
>>> L = [{'status': 1, 'country': 'France'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'canada'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'usa'}]
>>> L.sort(key= lambda x:x['country'])
>>> L
[{'status': 1, 'country': 'France'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'canada'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'usa'}]
```

You can pass an optional key word argument `reverse = True` to `sort` and `sorted` to sort in descending order.

As a upper-case alphabet is considered smaller than it's corresponding smaller-case version(due to their ASCII value), so you may have to use `str.lower` as well.

```
>>> L.sort(key= lambda x:x['country'].lower())
>>> L
[{'status': 1, 'country': 'canada'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'France'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'usa'}]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> L = [{'status': 1, 'country': 'France'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'canada'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'usa'}]
>>> sorted(L, key=itemgetter('country'))
[{'status': 1, 'country': 'France'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'canada'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'usa'}]
>>> sorted(L, key=itemgetter('country'), reverse=True)
[{'status': 1, 'country': 'usa'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'canada'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'France'}]
>>> sorted(L, key=itemgetter('status'))
[{'status': 1, 'country': 'France'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'canada'}, {'status': 1, 'country': 'usa'}]
```

Comment: I think we have to use `str.lower` here as dictionary wise `canada` must come before `France`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary if that's required then your answer should be accepted ;) I just followed what the question asked so I'll leave this here for other people visiting

Comment: @jamylak: AshwiniChaudhary has right, canada should come before france in the first short, actually the short is correct with `str.lower`

Answer (score 2):

Pulling the key out to a named function is a good idea for real code, because now you can write tests for it explicitly

```
def by_country(x):
    # For case insensitive ordering by country
    return x['country'].lower()

L.sort(key=by_country)
```

Of course you can adapt to use `sorted(L, key=...)` or `reverse=True` etc.